# Nodejs mongoose schema many to many relationship with attributes

Tags: node.js, mongoose, many-to-many, schema

I am writing a node express api with mongoose schema. I need to model a many-to-many relationship with additional attributes. My ER would be as following.
[image]

A normal many-to-many relationship would be like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    id: ObjectId,
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    ...
    courses: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Course'} ]
});

var CourseSchema = new Schema({
    id: ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    ...
    students: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User'} ]
});
```

> How can I model the additional attributes in the User-Course relationship?

Comment: Have you considered a new enrollment schema/model instead of nesting this data inside CourseSchema?

Comment: If your data is relational, perhaps you should consider using a relational database...

Comment: Yeah I might use a new model or change to relational DB. But first I need to clarify whether this is not posiible with mongoose.